# How to fix strange rails route: DELETE activity.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using the public_activity gem, rails 6.0.3.2, & ruby v2.71.

On the page that lists the tracked activities, I want to place a Destroy button for each record in the list of records. I have done so with the code shown below. However, I get a routing error. The route rails is looking for is

```
activity.id
```

I want the route to be

```
activity/:id
```

Here is the relevant portion of the html (HAML) view:

```
-@activities.each do |activity|
 ...<other code>...    
 .float-right
      = link_to 'Destroy', activity_path(activity), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger'
```

Here is the relevant route in my config/routes.rb file:

```
delete 'activity/:id', to: 'home#destroy_activity'
```

This route returns an error saying that "No route matches [DELETE] "/activity.239" (obviously different for each record id).

The Destroy button works just fine if I change the route to:

```
delete 'activity.:id', to: 'home#destroy_activity'
```

But that looks weird to me and I'd rather use a "normal" rails route.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Rails is having a convention issue with your route. Try adding `as: :delete` to the end of the route definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
activity_path(activity.id)
```

instead of:

```
activity_path(activity)
```

You have defined a custom route using `delete 'activity/:id', to: 'home#destroy_activity'` so this required the `id` of the object instead of the object itself. It is preferable to always add `:as` in the end of the route definition so you can do it like this:

```
delete 'activity/:id', to: 'home#destroy_activity', as: :activity_destroy
```

and then you can refer this path like this:

```
activity_destroy_path(activity.id)
```

The best way is to always have a separate controller for these things. So as you have created an action `destroy_activity` in the home controller instead you could create a separate `activities_controller` and just add routes like this as mentioned by [Kaom Te](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73095/kaom-te) in the below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63498212/4207394):

```
resources activities
```

This will by default generate the CRUD actions for activities but you can limit it by using `only` or `except`.

Comment: i had already tried activity_path(activity.id) and that did not work. But, changing the route as suggested and using the new path name as suggested (activity_destroy_path(activity.id)) did work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Rails encourages restful resources. Typically I would do something like this in my routes.rb file.

```
# Add others if appropriate... :create, :show... etc.
resources activities, only: [:destroy]
```

Which would be handled in activities_controller.rb by your ActivitiesController.

Then your link would be

```
= link_to 'Destroy', activity, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger'
```

Your ActivitiesController would look something like this

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @activity = PublicActivity::Activity.find(params[:id])
    @activity.destroy

    # Redirect or whatever here....
  end
```

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure how to do this. I am using the public_activity gem and it "packages" its functionality up as PublicActivity::Activity. I don't want to interfere with any of that built-in functionality.

Comment: I added details on what the controller should look like. I can't say 100 percent, since I don't use PublicActivity, but I would be a bit surprised if this messed up the built-in PublicActivity functionality.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll give it a try. That would be more like what I am accustomed to.